# How to add Public (External) IP Addresses to my private network (windows domain controller)

Tags: networking, routing, windows-domain

I have set up a private domain network at home.  I have a domain controller, a DNS server, and a DHCP server all running on one Windows 2003 Server machine.  I have about 10 other machines around the house, getting their IP addresses from this DHCP server.

I have a Netgear WNDR3700 router.

I am about to get 5 public IP addresses from my ISP, and I would like to make some of these machines publicly accessible (while still accessible from the other machines in the network).

I found [this link](http://dslwebserver.com/main/fr_index.html?/main/diagram-Multiple-IP-addresses-with-Router-and-Private-LAN.html) that says on my web server (one of the public machines), that I should use a second NIC and set that up to connect to my router (and get a private IP address from my DHCP server).

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could use 1:1 NAT. This would make them fully accessible to the network on their private, but accessible publicly via the public IP.

Comment: @MaQleod:  Make your comment an answer.

Comment: @Chris, added answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use 1:1 NAT. This would make them fully accessible to the network on their private, but accessible publicly via the public IP.

Comment: My router doesn't support that.  Is there an inexpensive router that you would recommend?  If I need to, I will use my existing router as an access point.